# Three dimensional Height and distance problem of trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

#### Due to limitation of characters in the title section the original problem is quoted here

A man finds that at a point due south of a tower the angle of elevation of the tower is 60 degrees. He then walks due west 10√6 metres on a horizontal plane and finds that the angle of elevation of the tower at that point is 30 degrees. Then the original distance of the man from the tower,in metres , is?

My attempt(See the picture [image])

Comment: You've taken a picture of a whole page... what are we supposed to look at?

Comment: Sorry for that I just wanted to know how to approach these questions as the traditional approach is going nowhere.

Comment: Are you supposed to care about the curvature of the Earth's surface?

Comment: I did not quite understand @ Arnaud Mortier

Comment: Please note: the title is for a brief description of the question and you should always put the full question in the body (where you have put it).

Comment: For future reference please avoid trying to make the title be the entire problem statement.  Readers will find it easier to parse your problem when the formatting faculties of the body are used to fullest extent, and the title can be something that briefly interests Readers in what you want to ask.

Comment: But the question is longer than the capacity of the title section?@Rob Arthan

Comment: Have you tried using vectors?

Comment: No no I haven't @Karn Watcharasupat. Please can anyone tell me how to tackle such problems. The last time I faced one such problem was years ago. I can't figure out anything productive now.

Comment: @Saradamani: so that's why you don't use the title for the full question, but just for a brief description. The place for the full question is the big box under the title, where, as hardmath points out, you have much more facilties for formatting and can write as much as you like.

Comment: Ok @Rob Arthan I will see to it and I will abide by the rules in future. I am quite new here.

Comment: @Saradamani: no worries. Welcome to MSE!

Comment: And also @Rob Arthan I come from an under privileged society of rural India. Here studying math is a challenge. Now getting access to internet is like a dream come true.So please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the tower to be PM with base M and height $x$  .And you first walk to A and then  horizontally  $10\sqrt6 $ m to B

now Triangles $\triangle PMA \triangle PMB  $ and $\triangle MBA $ are right angle triangles , with $\angle PAM = 60^\circ$ and $\angle PBM = 30^\circ$

in $\triangle PMA $

$cot(60^\circ) =  \frac{AM}{x} \implies AM = \frac{x}{\sqrt3}$

in $\triangle PMB $

$\cot(30^\circ) = \frac{MB}{x}\implies MB = \sqrt3 .x$

Therfore in $\triangle MBA$

$MB = \sqrt3.x, AB =10\sqrt6$ and $MA = \frac{x}{\sqrt3}$

Apply Pythagoras theorem ,

$(MA)^2+(BA)^2=(MB)^2$

$\frac{x^2}{3} +600=3x^2$

$x^2(\frac13-3)=-600$

$x^2 =\frac{(600 )(3)}{8}$

$x= 15 $m

hence the original distance $AM =\frac{15}{\sqrt3}$m

Comment: My only consideration was that $\Delta\space MBA \neq \space right\space angled \space  triangle$. Thats why I was stuck . Otherwise its a piece of cake.

Comment: You drew a 3d diagram, i always recommend drawing simple 2d diagrams first and extending to higher dimensions  . same with any question,try solving a simpler version and extend it to higher level.

Comment: Just as we do in Mathematical Induction. Right/? solve for the base case and then proceed higher. In computer science also, we use dynamic programming paradigm which uses a similar concept. Thanks a million times.

Comment: exactly , always helps in problems  and exams with confusing questions. happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the sides of a $60^o{-}30^o{-}90^o$ triangle are in the ratios $1:\frac{1}{2}:\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (this follows from the fact that $\sin\,30^o = \frac{1}{2}$). There are two such triangles in your problem each with the tower as one leg and one of the two observation points as the opposite vertex. Compare the ratios of the edges and conclude that the move west tripled the distance from the tower. Hence looking at the plan view of the situation you see a right-angled triangle with one leg and the hypotenuse in the ration $1:3$. Applying Pythagoras, the edges of the plan view triangle are in the ratio $1 : 2\sqrt{2} : 3$ and you are given the length of the longer of the two legs, from which you can calculate the length of the shorter leg, which is what you are asked for.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions for lots of information and figures involving $\sin$, $\cos$ etc.

Comment: The first part I have already done. This was an MCQ asked in a popular tough exam in India. My answer using that hint does not comply with the options.

Comment: @Saradamani Which exam?

Comment: ISI BMath exam year forgot.@pranavB23

Comment: I originally thought it was a JEE main or BITSAT question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ be the height of the tower, let $x$ be the distance you are trying to find, and let $y$ be the distance to the base of the tower in the second position.

The horizontal triangle is right-angled therefore $$y^2=x^2+(10\sqrt{6})^2$$

You also have, in the first position, $$h=x\tan60\implies x=\frac{h}{\sqrt{3}}$$
In the second position, $$h=y\tan30\implies y=h\sqrt{3}$$

Now substitute these expressions into the first equation and find $h$ then you can find $x$.